# VK API - проверка токена

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Добрый день!
Написал скрипт автоматической выгрузки товаров с интернет-магазина в фотоальбомы и товары в ВК. Намучался, но скрипт работает, тут всё ок.
Далее мне необходимо написать cron, который будет периодически обновлять инфу о товарах. При  авторизации пользователя выставил scope offline, чтобы токен не ограничивался временем.

При первом экспорте пользователь проходит авторизацию и получение токена.
После подтверждения пользователем прав доступа, данные о пользователе, включая сам токен, я сохраняю в базу.

Далее, при обновлении инфы о товаре, мне необходимо автоматически обновить описание товара, либо фотографии (в зависимости от того, какой тип экспорта выбрал пользователь) при помощи крона. И вот тут возникла проблема: как проверить, действителен ли токен?
secure.checkToken возвращает ошибку, когда я пытаюсь проверить access_token:
User authorization failed: invalid access_token

```
$params = array(
        'uids'         => $user_id, 
        'access_token' => $token
    );

    $result = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.vk.com/method/secure.checkToken' . '?' . urldecode(http_build_query($params))), true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, мне не совсем понятно, почему вы пытаетесь передавать именно такие параметры. Для [secure.checkToken](https://vk.com/dev/secure.checkToken) заявлено, что принимает два параметра: token (что само по себе любопытно, возможно нужен именно он, а не глобальный access_token. Либо оба. Не могу сейчас проверить) и необязательный ip. Никакого uids нет, user_id возвращается в ответ.

Второй момент, urldecode после http_build_query не нужен. http_build_query генерирует корректный query string. Необходимость его ломать означает только грубое нарушение стандартов второй стороной, а vk вроде со стандартами пока считается.

Как третий момент, обращаю внимание, что api без обязательного указания версии объявлено устаревшим и через несколько месяцев работать перестанет.

По вопросу как проверить, действителен ли токен - у вас же всё равно есть обработчик ответа от api. Там и проверяйте, на протухший токен возвращается вполне конкретный тип ошибок error_code = 5.